# Displaying applied AutoFilters using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm working on a data set which uses AutoFilters.
The workbook contains 2 sheets, with the 2nd one containing all the data and the option to apply filters, based of a frozen 1st row, filtering the information per column.
I want to have a display of cells in the first sheet of the workbook that show the user what filters are applied, or a blank cell if "Select All" is selected in the filter section.

After breaking my head and googling for what seemed like ages, I found an user-defined function, based on work from Microsoft MVP Stephen Bullen. The code look as follows:

```
Function DispCriteria(Rng As Range) As String
    Dim Filter As String

    Filter = ""
    On Error GoTo Done
    With Rng.Parent.AutoFilter
        If Intersect(Rng, .Range) Is Nothing Then GoTo Done
        With .Filters(Rng.Column - .Range.Column + 1)
            If Not .On Then GoTo Done
            Filter = .Criteria1
            Select Case .Operator
                Case xlAnd
                    Filter = Filter & " AND " & .Criteria2
                Case xlOr
                    Filter = Filter & " OR " & .Criteria2
            End Select
        End With
    End With
Done:
    DispCriteria = Filter
End Function
```

Using this function seemed to work, displaying :

> =Filter1 OR =Filter2

as output in the cells where I entered the following :

```
=DispCriteria(C:C)
```

where Filter1 & Filter 2 would be the active filters and the range C:C would be specified to the necessary range that the filters would be working on.

However, the moment I would activate more than 2 filters (e.g. 3), the output would be a blank cell instead of the desired:

> =Filter1 OR =Filter2 OR =Filter3

I don't understand much about how the function works and cant find any additional information on it. I tried tweaking it to allow for more than 2 filters to show, to no succes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @dadler Damn it. And I just typed up an answer :-)

Comment: @QHarr ^^' I was typing up mine when I thought "I'm almost certain I learned this one form a SO answer..."

Comment: @dadler #Ishouldhavegoogled :-(